# Quiero crear este proyecto con mi propia lista

Tags: android-fragment, recyclerview, lista, searchview, toolbar

He hecho este proyecto con este tutorial: http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-filter-recyclerview-using-searchview-in-toolbar.html, el.problema es el siguiente: quiero usar mi propia lista, en vez de la lista de paises como se utiliza en este tutorial.

Debo decir que no tengo conocimiento avanzado en programación. Solo aprendo con lo que encuentro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente cambia los valores que le pasas al `adapter` cuando lo estás creando (clase `TabOneFragment` línea 49)

```
adapter = new RVAdapter(mCountryModel);
```

En este caso `mCountryModel` es una lista de `CountryModel`, por lo tanto podrías hacer algo así:

```
mCountryModel = new ArrayList<>();
mCountryModel.add(new CountryModel("Pais 1", "Codigo 1");
mCountryModel.add(new CountryModel("Pais 2", "Codigo 2");
mCountryModel.add(new CountryModel("Pais 3", "Codigo 4");
adapter = new RVAdapter(mCountryModel);
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```